# how can i pass cookie from request header to selenium cookie

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, python-requests

I want to use the cookie taken from the request header to log into the account of a web site opened with selenium python
my problem is that i don't want to add cookies one by one

[For example](https://streamable.com/iqrvtc)

this is form my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import pickle
import time
import os
import requests

cookie = ("input cookie from request header: ")

# convert to selenium cookie

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get('https://www.example.com/')

# add the newly converted cookie

driver.refresh()
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.